# TimePicker output not showing the picket time correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, time

I need to get a time from a timepicker and show it on a text widget.
Here you have the widget that should show the time:

```
pickedTime = TimeOfDay.now();
    
ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                      " ${pickedTime.hour}:${pickedTime.minute}"),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.timer,size: 45,),
                  onTap: _pickTime,
                ),
```

And here you have the  function _pickTime:

```
  _pickTime() async{
    TimeOfDay time = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: pickedTime);
    setState(() {
      pickedTime = time;

    });

  }
```

I have detected an issue when the picked time hour or minute is smaller than 10, the output is as shown in the picture for 04:05:

[image]

I would like to show the picked time always in format HH:mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an extension on the `int` class that you can use to enforce two characters for each part of the time:

```dart
extension TwoChar on int {
  String toTwoChars() {
    return this.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  }
}
```

Then modify your code to use the extension:

```dart
title: Text("${pickedTime.hour.toTwoChars()}:${pickedTime.minute.toTwoChars()}"),
```